# What's the difference between "at the end" and "by the end"?

Tags: meaning, grammar

If the subject is the (end times). What would be the difference between the following:

1. At the end of the (end times)
2. By the end of the (end times)

Comment: "At" means it happens when the end arrives.  "By" means it happens sometime before the end such that it is complete when the end arrives.

Comment: End times?? As in end of days? The apocalypse? Or the ending time, a time when something ends?

Answer (score 1):

The use of [by](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/by) allows the person performing the task to complete it any time *up until* the specified time.

The use of [at](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/at) specifies the exact and *only* time the task must be completed.

`"I want my will updated at the end times"` - Exactly at the end time, not a minute sooner or later.

`"I want my will updated by the end times"` - Before the end time.